# $\int_{\Omega}|fg|d \mu \leq ||f||_2||g||_2$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f,g \in \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega, \mu)$.

We have that $\int_{\Omega}|fg|d \mu \leq \|f\|_2\|g\|_2$

I would like to prove it, without applying directly Cauchy–Schwarz inequality.

I would proceed in the following way:

Show that $\int_{\Omega}|fg|d \mu \leq \|f\|_2\|g\|_2$ is true for

1. $\|f\|_2=0$ or $\|g\|_2=0$.
2. $\|f\|_2=1 = \|g\|_2$.
3. $\|f\|_2 \neq 0$ and $\|g\|_2 \neq 0$.

Can someone show me how to do one case? Hopefully I can do the rest alone then.

Comment: OK, let's try the first. What can you say about $\int_{\Omega} \lvert fg\rvert \, d\mu$ if $\lVert f\rVert=0$ or $\lVert g \rVert=0$? What does the inequality $$\int_{\Omega} \lvert fg\rvert \, d\mu\le \lVert f\rVert\lVert g\rVert$$ reduce to, in this case?

Comment: A couple points:  Case (1) follows from $\int |f| d\mu = 0 \iff \mu(x : f(x)\neq 0) = 0$.  Similarly, Case (3) follows from Case (2) by linearity of the integral and bilinearity of the product.  That is, the only case of any real depth we should consider is (2).

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please,  upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case $1$**: For any $h \in \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega, \mu)$, if $\|h\|_2=0$ then $\int |h|^2 d\mu =0$, so $|h| = 0$ $a.e.$, so $h=0$ $a.e.$.

So we have that, if $\|f\|_2=0$ or $\|g\|_2=0$ then $f=0$ $a.e.$ or $g=0$ $a.e.$. So $fg=0$ $a.e.$, so $| fg| =0$ $a.e.$,
$$\int_{\Omega}|fg|d \mu =0 \leq 0=\|f\|_2\|g\|_2$$

**Case $2$**:  If $\|f\|_2=1 = \|g\|_2$, the we have $\int |f|^2 d\mu =1$ and $\int |g|^2 d\mu =1$.

Note that $(|f|-|g|)^2 \geq 0$. So
$$\int_\Omega (|f|-|g|)^2 d\mu \geq 0$$
So, we have,
$$\int_\Omega |f|^2 d\mu +  \int_\Omega |g|^2 d\mu -2 \int_\Omega |fg|d\mu = \int_\Omega (|f|-|g|)^2 d\mu \geq 0$$
Since $\int |f|^2 d\mu =1$ and $\int |g|^2 d\mu =1$, we have
$$2 -2 \int_\Omega |fg|d\mu \geq 0$$
So
$$\int_\Omega |fg|d\mu \leq 1 = \|f\|_2 \|g\|_2$$

**Case $3$**: If $\|f\|_2 \neq 0$ and $\|g\|_2 \neq 0$. Then let $\hat{f} =\frac{f}{\|f\|_2}$ and $\hat{g} =\frac{g}{\|g\|_2}$. Clearly, $\hat{f}, \hat{g} \in \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega, \mu)$ and $\|\hat{f}\|_2=1 = \|\hat{g}\|_2$. So, by **Case $2$**, we have

$$\int_\Omega |\hat{f}\hat{g}|d\mu \leq 1 = \|\hat{f}\|_2 \|{g}\|_2$$

But, since $\hat{f} =\frac{f}{\|f\|_2}$ and $\hat{g} =\frac{g}{\|g\|_2}$, we have

$$\frac{1}{\|f\|_2\|g\|_2 }\int_\Omega |fg|d\mu=\int_\Omega |\hat{f}\hat{g}|d\mu \leq 1 $$
So
$$\int_\Omega |fg|d\mu \leq  \|f\|_2 \|g\|_2$$

**Remark**: From **Case $1$** and **Case $3$** we have that $$\int_\Omega |fg|d\mu \leq  \|f\|_2 \|g\|_2$$  is valid for all  $f, g \in \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega, \mu)$.